# Why does an electron diffraction pattern of a crystal come out to be visible in the reciprocal space?

Tags: diffraction, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I have been recently trying to understand electron diffraction patterns of crystals. What I am not able to visualise is the reason why a diffraction pattern of the reciprocal space is formed on the screen (The image looks similar to that attached below. Please explain why does this pattern looks exactly like the reciprocal lattice of the crystal). Can someone please explain this in as straightforward manner as possible? The answer can be as long as possible, as long as the clearest explanation is provided. The use of appropriate diagrams for visualization is highly appreciated.

(Image source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Austenite_ZADP.jpg)

[image: Image source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Austenite_ZADP.jpg]

Comment: What do you mean by 'reciprocal space'?

Comment: The collimated electron beam gets momenta kicks from allowed reciprocal lattice vectors, so spreads out along specific directions determined by those vectors.

Comment: Found this mathematical explanation http://physics.unl.edu/tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/Section%2002_X-ray_Diffraction.pdf